# Where else can I find Styles in Joomla! with k2 than in templates?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have to design one website, but it has to be done in joomal, and I do not have to much experience with it. I have set up a template and it looks like [this](http://iiicstest.eu/index.php/about/testimonials). But I need to restyle it to be similar to this: [image]. I want from you that name of module or template or sub-template where can I specify for example that the date will be allign to right side in the same line with the title. Because I cannot find it anywhere. In templates there are only globa options, to change the whole look of the site. But the local css or style options are nowhere.  thanks a lot for Your answers.

Comment: what exactly you want to change. if you want to whole template then let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are just starting, for academic purposes you may read about the 960 grid system used by some Joomla template frameworks.

The best framework I have seen, and it is my own opinion, is Gantry from Rocket Themes. Its is easy to place modules in the layout and align the modules using a graphic interface. they use a 12 column 960 px default layout.

visit it here: www.gantry-framework.org

Check out the video on this page: **www.gantry-framework.org/documentation/joomla/customize/adding-module-positions**

I found their documentation far better than most other template frameworks for joomla.

Using a good framework makes it very easy to get ur work done, probably reduce it by many many hours.

And its free, just FYI.